# Assigning different reactive objects conditionally in R Shiny's reactive framework

Tags: r, shiny

I want to assign different reactive objects to another reactive object in R Shiny based on certain conditions. I have created two modules: uploadFileServer and uploadRdsServer. When user uploads required input files, uploadFileServer performs some processing and returns the processed data. When user upload .rds file, uploadRdsServer reads and returns it. I want to assign the return value of uploadFileServer to myData() when the user uploads input files, and assign the return value of uploadRdsServer to myData() when the user uploads an .rds file.

I wrote the following code for this purpose. However, although this code assigns runData() to myData(), it does not assign rdsData() to myData(). How can I modify it to make it work correctly in this situation?

```
runData <- uploadFileServer("upload_file")
rdsData <- uploadRdsServer("upload_rds")

myData <- reactive({
  if (!is.null(runData())){
    runData()
  } else if (!is.null(rdsData())){
    rdsData()
  }
})
```